# Subsetting a data.frame by a numerical vector

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 358 rows

```
df <- data.frame(A=rnorm(358),B=rnorm(358))
```

and want to subset at these breaks:

```
breaks <- c(59,119,178,238,298)
```

resulting in six dataframes with

59, 60, 59, 60, 60, 60 rows.

(This is a result of a 6 x 60 sampling design, of which two samples have been lost.)

Is this possible?

Comment: `n = c(59, 60, 59, 60, 60, 60); split(df, rep(seq_along(n), n))` ?

Comment: Why is this not an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you fancy a primitive loop solution you can simply iterate through you desired row numbers, I understand that you are interested in subsetting this data frame by row numbers.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(A=rnorm(358),B=rnorm(358)) 
## Added 1
breaks <- c(1, 59,119,178,238,298, 358)

listDFs <- vector("list", length(breaks) - 1)

for (i in 1:(length(breaks)-1)) {
  # Take observations from this to that row
  listDFs[[i]] <- df[breaks[i]:breaks[i+1],]
}
```

---

### Side point

I reckon that suggestion provided in comments by [@Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1191259/frank) is better:

```
n = c(59, 60, 59, 60, 60, 60); split(df, rep(seq_along(n), n))
```

Loop would make sense if you are you looking for a visually convenient way to do more things on the generated object.

---

## Results

```
> sapply(listDFs, dim)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]   59   61   60   61   61   61
[2,]    2    2    2    2    2    2
```

Comment: I preferred Frank's solution for being easier to work with in my singular case. I appreciate your thinking and your help though.

Comment: @nouse No problem, glad that I was able to contribute. If you fancy, you can always try to [*microbenchmark*](http://www.r-bloggers.com/microbenchmarking-with-r/) code variants and explore performance differences on your actual data.

Comment: The output does not match op's description

Comment: @PierreLafortune I figured that the request is to chunk the `data.frame` into separate `data.frames` of specific sizes; one could adjust sizes changing the break values any way desired, for simplicity I took the original ones but can be effortlessly altered to reflect chunks of other sizes.

Comment: It is more than a matter of "adjusting". `listDFs[[1]][59,1]` should not be equal to `listDFs[[2]][1,1]`, but it is in your example because your loop was ill-constructed.

Comment: If you add 0 instead of 1 to the start of breaks and extract `(breaks[i]+1):breaks[i+1]`, it should work.

Comment: The loop one is a nonsense as is, last line of each subsetted df is the first line of next df... Not downvoting because of the inclusion of a correct answer, but not upvoting either. (Even more when your results section prove it does not match OP expectation, just add the first row of your sapply result to get you're having more rows than inital dataset)